# SAS replacing a specific pattern without space back in the text

Tags: regex, sas

For eg my text is like this- "I have these codes c 6780, u 6780, c0555". What the output is currently giving is- "I have these codes ([cu][0-9o][0-9a-z]{3}), ([cu][0-9o][0-9a-z]{3}), c0545". But what I am expecting is 
"I have these codes c6780, u6780, c0555".
I tried this code.

```
DATA REPLACE_PAT;
set text;
IF _N_ =1 THEN PATTERN = PRXPARSE ("s/([cu]\s[0-9o][0-9a-z]{3})/([cu][0-9o][0-9a-z]{3})/");
RETAIN PATTERN;
CALL PRXCHANGE(PATTERN, -1, text); 
run;
```

How do I change my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the bits you want to keep in parens (not the whole thing) to create capture groups, then refer to the capture groups using `$1` `$2`.

```
DATA REPLACE_PAT;
  set text;
  IF _N_ =1 THEN PATTERN = PRXPARSE ("s/([cu])\s([0-9o][0-9a-z]{3})/$1$2/");
  RETAIN PATTERN;
  CALL PRXCHANGE(PATTERN, -1, text); 
run;
```

You also might want to look into the `o` option after the final `/` to avoid having to do the silly if *n* = 1 bit.

Comment: what if I have ("s/([cu][o][0-9a-z][0-9][0-9a-z])/([cu][0][0-9a-z][0-9][0-9a-z])/"). Trying to change letter o to zero(second character)?

Comment: The section after the middle `/` does not do any sort of pattern matching.  It just puts whatever is there, into the string, excepting the `$` variables.  So you would do `/$10$2/` for the replace section; except because `0` makes it look like you want the 10th `$10` not `$1` and 0, I'm not sure how to make SAS recognize what you actually want.  You may want to ask that as a question, and see if some of the RegEx people know how to do that.  (RegEx Buddy is able to figure out that we want just $1, which is unfortunate since that means I can't use it to test.)

Comment: Also, tag any such question [tag:Regex].